# jQuery sometimes loads all the values but sometimes misses some values

Tags: javascript, jquery, tastypie

Hello Guys I'm working on a Q&A using django-tastypie.

In my template in need to print all the questions related to a topic and all the answers related to a particular question, for this I passed an object to jQuery file and iterate that object there.

this is the code

```
$(data.quiztopics).each(function(index,element){  
   $(element.questions).each(function(index,question){  
     $(".quiz").append("<table id='question_"+question.id+">"+
                       "<tr><p name='question' id=question_"+question.id+">"+
                          (question.question_text) +
                       "</p></tr><tr id=answer_"+question.id+"></tr>"); 

$(question.answers).each(function(index,answer){
     $("#answer_"+question.id).append("<td>"+
        "<input type='radio' name='answer'id=answer_"+answer.id+">"+ 
            answer.answer_text +
        "</input></td>"); 
});
```

in console.log it shows everything all right i,e answer related to particular question. bt when i append it to a table row it misses answers of some of the questions 
i.e

```
10+10

120 20  30  1
10*10

100 00  20  1
10/10

10-10
```

please tell me the solution how can i got to place all answers under a related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have solved this problem. might be I had some syntax errors or something else. I removed the code and wrote it again and it works perfectly now.
the new code is here.
$(data.quiztopics).each(function(index,element){

```
                $(element.questions).each(function(index,question){
                    $(".quiz").append("<table class= question_"+question.id+"><tr><td>"+question.question_text+"</td></tr></table>");
                    $(".question_"+question.id).append("<tr class=answer_"+question.id+"></tr>")
                    $(question.answers).each(function(index,answer){
                        if(question.question_type=="NUM"){
                            $(".answer_"+question.id).append("<td><input type=radio name="+question.id+"/> "+answer.answer_text+"</td>");
                        }

                    })

                })
```

but now my next question is that this is a quiz and i need to submit it. Please tell me how can i loop over the given questions and answers and select the particular answer to submit the quiz.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are not closing the table tag, that is added each time, but never closed and that might #$!!!$ something up. You should add the tag outside the "each", or close it each time. The rest of your code **looks** ok.

As another suggestion... you should modify your data structure to keep answer as an element of the question. This would solve you current problem, optimize your code (no need for the second selector in and modification in dom), and make you feel good about yourself :).

Comment: Yes, i was missing the closing table tag. bt it doesn't work now too.  actually what i want to do is that i want to append these questions and answers on a template like a quiz. I made multiple table and answer tr separate in each table  bcz while submitting the quiz i can easily loop over the tables in quiz id     and grab the values from td. please tell me if there is any other way to achieve this quiz displaying and submitting task